# Does an inverse exist for a set of complex numbers with operation of multiplication?

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

I will give some context of my question: I was trying to solve this problem

> Let $S$ be a finite non-empty set of non-zero complex numbers which is closed under multiplication. Show that $S$ is a subset of the set $\{z \in \mathbb C: |z|=1 \}$. Show that $S$ is a group, and deduce that for some $n \in \mathbb N$, S is the set of n-th roots of unity.

When trying to prove that $S$ is a subset of $\{z \in \mathbb C: |z|=1 \}$, I tried to argue that since $S$ is closed, $\forall a \in S, \ \exists \ \text{a corresponding} \ n \in \mathbb N^+ $ such that $$a^n = a \tag{1}$$ and hence $|a|=1$.

Now I want to prove that the identity element is in $S$, can I argue from $(1)$ that $a^{n-1}=e=1$?

Comment: yes $a^n\to a^{n-1}=1$ because $a\ne 0$.  But you want $n>1$ in (1).

Comment: @user254665 Yeah intuitively I think this is so. I am a bit careful because the question only says $S$ is a set and hence may not have an inverse. Also, the only information I can get from the word 'closed' is that $a^n=a$ for some $n$. How is it justified that one can find an inverse to show that $a^{n-1}=e$?

Comment: @Rescy_ : you're in a field. Sure, the inverse may not be in $S$, but the equality still hold

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is correct: for each $a \in S$, the finiteness of $S$ implies that there is an $n_a \in \Bbb N \setminus \{ 1 \}$ such that $a^ {n_a} = 1$. Since $S$ is closed under multiplication, it follows that $1 = a \cdot a \cdot \dots \cdot a \in S$. Finally, $a ^{-1} = a ^{n_a - 1} \in S$, so $S$ is a group.

Comment: I may be late here but I am just trying to understand how does it imply if $S$ is finite, there is $n$ s.t. $a^n=e$? OP also said closeness gives the same implication. Are they both equivalent?

Comment: @AndrésdeFonollosa: This is a standard elementary argument: consider the consecutive powers $1, a, a^2, a^3, \dots$. These infinitely many powers cannot be distinct elements of $S$, because $S$ is finite! Therefore there exist $m, n \in \mathbb N$ with $m<n$ such that $a^m = a^n$, i.e. $a^{n-m} = 1$. Let $n_a = n-m$ and this is it.

Answer (score 1):

To prove this in the order suggested:

- Let $a \in S$. If $|a|>1$, then $1 < |a| < |a|^2 < \cdots $ and the powers of $a$ would be an infinite subset of $S$. The same would follow if $|a|<1$. Thus, $|a|=1$.
- Let $S$ have $n$ elements. Consider $x \mapsto ax$. This is injective and so is surjective. Therefore $a_1 \cdots a_n = (a a_1) \cdots (a a_n) = a^n a_1 \cdots a_n$ and so $a^n=1$, which proves in one stroke that $S$ is a group formed by $n$-roots of unity. Since $n$ has $n$ elements, $S$ is the set of all $n$-roots of unity.

(This last argument is the proof of the little Lagrange theorem for finite abelian groups.)